KiCad simulator .lib sihf840.lib unimplemented control card - error
Im new to KiCad, Im trying to simulate AC-DC rectifier with IRF840 mosfet, but got stuck at launching simulation.
I have used pspice models for all components, and then wanted to attach an "irf840" model (.lib) taken from https://www.vishay.com/en/product/91070/tab/designtools-ppg/ to 4 terminal pspice MNMOS mosfet on my schematic.
Unfortunatelly got the error in simulator:

Note: No compatibility mode selected! Circuit: KiCad schematic Error on line 41 or its substitute: .lib sihf840.lib unimplemented control
card - error  Error: circuit not parsed.

I even shrinked the .lib code just to (did not help, still getting same error at line "41" even though Ive got only 5 lines):
.subckt irf840 1 2 3 4
M1 1 2 3 4 MM
Rbody 4 3 1e-6
.MODEL MM NMOS LEVEL=1 VTO=3.5 KP=10
.ends irf840

Yes, Im using the directives on my schematic
.tran 0.1m 10m
.lib sihf840.lib

Would be glad to hear suggestions to resolve this issue.
